# UndefVarError: Model not defined

Tags: julia, jupyter, julia-jump, ijulia-notebook

How should I fix the following error?

```
Pkg.add("JuMP")
Pkg.add("Clp")
m = Model()
```

and I get the following error:

```
LoadError: UndefVarError: Model not defined
while loading In[4], in expression starting on line 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `using JuMP` before calling `m=Model()`